# Adding Basic Red Square On Canvas In Wordpress Via Fabric JS

Tags: wordpress, html, canvas, fabricjs

I've create a Wordpress Theme with Bootstrap & have been trying to load just the basic red square from the tutorial onto the canvas in my html.

```
    // create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});

// "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
```

- The script is loaded & when I console.log the canvas object it outputs the canvas object & it's properties. But, nothing will appear on the canvas. I've made sure my id's match & that my canvas is between a wrapper & has 1000 / 1000 px space set, which is centered.
- Below is my Template Code

  ```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1 class="test-header">Test Your Ad Here!</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div>
      <canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"> </canvas>
   </div>

   <hr/>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
  ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's not rendering but one thing to try is calling `canvas.renderAll()` to make sure fanric knows it's time to render it's data to the canvas.

Comment: I through renderAll() after adding my `rect` to my canvas. Still nothing is displayed.

Comment: can you add your code to a code snippet or a jsfiddle? Or check your console for any relevant errors?

Comment: Yeah, there aren't any errors. That's what's funky. Like when I console log the canvas object I've created, after adding the `rect` to it, it will print it the canvas object with all properties & methods belonging to it. There are no errors. I'm using Wordpress & installed it via Bower on my custom theme, I've linked it appropriate in my wp_enqueue_script() & works, but won't display anything.

Comment: if I simple add the fabric script to the top of the html part it seems to work just fine: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>
`

Comment: Yeah, I started a blank template & used the cdn on the local template file rather than the bower install, and it worked perfectly. Weird.